# Find the area of quadrilateral PC1QC2

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles, area

$ABCD$ is a quadrilateral with side lengths $AB=4$, $BC=10$, $CD=6$ and $AD=6$, and diagonal $BD=8$. If the incircles of triangles $ABD$ and $BCD$ touch $BD$ at $P$ and $Q$ respectively, then area of the quadrilateral $C_1PC_2Q$ (where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are the incenters of the $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle BCD$ respectively), is?

Comment: $DA=CD$ implies $BD$ is the bisector of $\angle ADC$. Can you use it? Or alternatively we can find $DQ$ and $DP$ explicitly (the segments of the tangents drawn from one point are equal, we have $3$ linear equations over $3$ variables) along with $r_{DBC},\, r_{DBA}$ and hence find all the sides of the desired quadrilateral.

Comment: Ohkk Thnx for the help I will try this approach.

Comment: Yeah I got it thanks for the help

Comment: You can edit your answer then to include geogebra drawings (optional) and MathJax expressions (almost mandatory) to show your work and get some upvotes) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found $DQ=2$ correctly. Now you must find $BP$. Apply Cosine theorem for $\triangle ABD$:
$$AD^2=AB^2+BD^2-2AB\cdot BD\cdot \cos ABD \Rightarrow \\
\cos ABD=\frac{4^2+8^2-6^2}{2\cdot 4\cdot 8}=\frac{11}{16} \Rightarrow \\
\cos (2\cdot \frac{ABD}2)=2\cos^2(\frac{ABD}2)-1=\frac{11}{16} \Rightarrow \\
\cos^2(\frac{ABD}2)=\frac{27}{32}=\frac{1}{1+\tan^2 (\frac{ABD}2)}\Rightarrow \\
\tan (\frac{ABD}2)=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{3\sqrt{3}}=\frac{C_1P}{BP}\Rightarrow \\
BP=\frac{3\sqrt{3}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{15}}{3}}{\sqrt{5}}=3$$
Hence, $PQ=BD-BP-DQ=8-3-2=3$.

Can you finish it yourself?

Answer:

> $A=\frac12\cdot PQ\cdot\left(C_1P+C_2Q\right)=\frac12\cdot 3\cdot \left(\frac{\sqrt{15}}{3}+2\right).$

Answer (score 0):

So here is my attempt,
[image]

After doing this I found myself at a deadend since there seems to be no way to find PQ.
Please help if you can. You can do it by a  different approach. Thanks in  advance :)

Comment: What are the data, exactly?

Comment: Check below the main question the lengths of sides of the quadrilateral and diagonals are given, that's all the data.

Comment: Please post your attempt in the question.

Comment: I have done it, is it not been displayed?

Comment: $BDC$ is a right angle therefore $DQ=2$

Comment: Edit your question to include this attempt instead of putting it as an answer. Try writing it in mathjax as well instead of posting a picture, [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) will help with the syntax.

Comment: Yeah right DQ will be 2, But how to find BP then?